# How to set icc color profile in Java and change colorspace

Tags: java, jai, icc, color-space, jmagick

First, I would like to say I'm not an image processing specialist.

I would like to convert image colorspace from one to another, and change icc color profile at the same time. I managed to do it using JMagick (the ImageMagick Java port), but no way in pure Java (even using JAI).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ColorConvertOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html), this will do the color space conversion. You have several options to set a icc color profile. Either you use a predefined profile by using `getInstance` with the correct color space constant or you can specify a file, which contains a profile. Here is an example:

```
ICC_Profile ip = ICC_Profile.getInstance( ColorSpace.CS_sRGB );
ICC_ColorSpace ics = new ICC_ColorSpace( ip );
ColorConvertOp cco = new ColorConvertOp( ics, null );
BufferedImage result = cco.filter( sourceImage, null );
```

The `result` will contain an image with the `sRGB` color space.